# How can I prevent `pod install` from adding libPods.a to the "Link binary with Libraries" build phase without creating a new target?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, cocoapods

I'm working on a static library whose dependencies are specified in its **podspec** file and will not be part of the library.

In order to develop against these dependencies I've created a **Podfile** which references the local **.podspec file**. After running `pod install` I can now use the workspace created by CocoaPods and no longer get build failures when referencing dependencies.

This is all desirable apart from that **libPods.a** is added to the "Link binary with Libraries" build phase. I don't want this since I don't want to include dependencies. I can manually remove it and all is well until the next time I run pod install.

To reiterate; my question is, how can I prevent that entry from appearing in the build phase? As mentioned in the title, I want to do this without needing to create a "dummy" target which is a technique that can be used to make CocoaPods link with that target instead.

If I can't prevent it due to some limitation with CocoaPods, can I make use of the CocoaPods `post_install` hook or add a "Run Script" build phase to remove it?

Comment: I possibly also don't want the "Copy Pods Resources" build phase, but I'm not sure what that does.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the integration you can use:

```
$ pod install --no-integrate
```

Comment: I tried this but then dependencies could not be found.

I think technically I do want the integration, just not the build phase.

Comment: @PaulYoung `libPods` is linked exactly for this purpose: to make the compilation objects of the dependencies available to the integrated targets.

Comment: it appears that I can delete the build phase and the build still succeeds. Whatever is causing that is all I need.

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing. @Fabio is there an opposite to "link_with", to prevent the dependencies being added to OTHER_LDFLAGS? It would be useful to use pods for the headers without also having to link in the binaries.